# Raspberry Pi as WiFi Bridge on Same Subnet

Tags: networking, raspberry-pi, bridge, wireless-bridge

I currently have my Raspberry Pi 4B setup as a bridge to provide wifi access to a separate ethernet device that can't do wifi. I used Option 1 from the guide here: https://willhaley.com/blog/raspberry-pi-wifi-ethernet-bridge/ which is based on an earlier question that was answered here: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/88954/workaround-for-a-wifi-bridge-on-a-raspberry-pi-with-proxy-arp/88955#88955

It works! The client device connects to the network via the bridge just fine and gets its own appropriate IP address from my network's main DHCP server that's in the correct subnet. However, in the DHCP list, the client device is sharing the same spot on the list as the Raspberry Pi that's acting as the bridge. So in my DHCP's GUI, the list of clients only displays the Pi's hostname (not the bridged client's), and its IP address vascillates between the Pi's and the client's every couple minutes.

In real life, I can access either device via their respective IP addresses or hostnames without any issues. The problem is mainly cosmetic in the DHCP's displayed list. However it also makes it difficult to figure out the client's IP address, especially if it changes because I'm plugging in something different. Is there a way to tweak the changes I've made so that the device connecting via the bridge has its own item in the DHCP list rather than the bridge's? Is this a MAC address translation issue? The item in the DHCP list has the Pi's wifi MAC address.

Note that I don't have access to raw files or logs for the DHCP server, it's not an open system.

Answer (score 1):

If you read a script in the *Option 1*, you wouldn't find any Linux bridge related commands there. No `brctl`, no `ip link set master`. But you can see it enables IP routing explicitely instead: `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`. Also if you'll read it carefully, you'll definitely encounter some strange term, a *proxy arp*.
So you should deduce this is not a bridge. And surely, **only IPv4** will work through Raspberry Pi if it's configured like this. If that was a true bridge, any protocol has to work. So it is incorrect to call this "bridging".

The following is basically a description of how `proxy arp` works.

---

Indeed, we enabled IP routing, so Raspberry Pi works as a **router**. What is unusual is that this router has "same" subnet behind two different interfaces. So some questions arise:

1. How does the router know which hosts are behind which interface?
2. How do other hosts behind both intefaces know that have some packets route through Raspberry Pi, instead of "sending them directly" as usual?

First one is easy. There aren't same network behind both interfaces. WLAN side has usual, say, 192.168.1.x **/24** address, but the address for the LAN is set to  192.168.1.x **/32** by the script. So in general Raspberry Pi doesn't have a subnet behind a LAN, and it only has wide enought subnet behind WLAN interface. But, when some host appears behind LAN, a dedicated route is added for it, that says this host is behind LAN. In this case, a `dhcp-helper` is responsible for installing such route. If you want to configure a host statically, you'll need to add this route also by hand on the Raspberry Pi.

Now, second one. A host behind LAN has a 192.168.1.y **/32** address, a direct route to Raspberry Pi and a default route through Raspberry Pi, so it has an usual way to reach everything through it. It doesn't think everybody is it's neighbour, only Raspberry Pi (which is true). But other hosts behind WLAN still think that host is their direct neighbour based on the netmask. Still, to reach that host we need them to send packets via Raspberry Pi. How to do that? The answer is: *Raspberry Pi answers ARP requests about that 192.168.1.y IP address with its own MAC address*, despite the fact it doesn't have that address assigned. It's some kind of ARP spoofing. So all other hosts happily send packets for the host 192.168.1.y to the Raspberry Pi, and it finds out the destination address is not local and forwards them properly via the LAN inteface. This setup is called a `proxy arp` (guess why).

Now, we must ask another question:

3. How it's possible that DHCP works for a host that's behind a proxy arp?

DHCP uses broadcast packets which don't get routed. So how DHCP server receives a queries and where it sends replies? This is again where `dhcp-helper` helps, it must act as a DHCP server for the LAN side, but instead of managing addresses locally it reissues a request from whe WLAN interface. So it acts as a *DHCP proxy* here.

But, if so, the request now has Raspberry Pi WLAN MAC address. Nothing we can do about it. This is precisely the issue why we can't bridge WLAN with LAN: an access point will accept only packets from authenicated MAC address, which is WLAN MAC, so mobile station only may send packets with it's WLAN card MAC address. The DHCP server sees a request from Raspberry Pi WLAN MAC; it is the MAC address is records into the lease.

The only way to distingush them is additional DHCP attributes: a Client ID; a Circuit ID which dhcp-helper may attach and so on; but all those attributes only visible to the DHCP server and if has no provision to display or use them, you can't see them.

---

So, recap. This is not bridging, but routing. The `proxy arp` feature enables a router to "fake" itself as that host behind just to receive packets destined for him, but this means each host in the WLAN will have router's WLAN MAC address in the ARP entry for any host behind proxy arp router. And as it is always in the routing you only see the MAC address of the nearest gateway and have no way to know MAC addresses of hosts behind it.

Comment: Excellent description. I think I need to rethink my approach. I want the Pi and any device connected to its LAN port to be able to talk to each other regardless of whether the Pi is connected to a wifi network with a DHCP server. But if the Pi is connected to a wifi network, I want to be able to easily access any daemon services running on a device behind the Pi from any computer on the network. Is it possible to use the dnsmasq method (instead of proxy arp) for routing, and yet have certain port requests to the Pi be routed to any device behind its LAN port?

Comment: I am not sure what did you mean with the "dnsmasq method"; `dnsmasq` is software, partially implementing DHCP, DNS, TFTP services, just a "swiss army knife" for a home router. But you can route, of course, you're already routing, what's missing?